# Drools - Check objects inside multiple nested Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, drools

I'm using drools to make a validation service to validate input XMLs (which are parsed to a Java object) for rules.

These XML-Files usually have a lot of data and some of that data is packed really deep inside multiple arrays and objects:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rckt3.jpg)

Now I need to check the value in "attributeValueFrom". Or for a matter of fact I have troubles accessing any object "deeper" down the tree than "condition".

```
rule "Every_Attribute_has_a_Value_True"
when
    G10EValidationObject($columns : getNormalisedMetaDataContainer().getMetaDataContainer().getNormalisedOrder().getSelection().getColumn());
    $column : NormalisedDataColType($condition : attributeCondition.getCondition()) from $columns;

    $column3 : NormalisedDataColType($attrValueGroup : attributeCondition.condition.getAttrValueGroup()) from $condition;
    //$column2 : NormalisedDataColType ($attrValueGroup : condition.getAttrValueGroup()) from $condition;
    $attrValueRanges : QualifiedAttributeNameValueGroupType(valueGroup.getValueRange()) from $attrValueGroups;
    $attrValueRange : QualifiedAttributeNameValueGroupType(valueRange.getAttributeValueFrom() != "", valueRange.getAttributeValueFrom() != null, valueRange.getAttributeValueTo() != "", valueRange.getAttributeValueTo() != null ) from $attrValueRanges;      
then
    validationRuleResults.addResult("Every_Attribute_has_a_Value", true, "Rule passed");
```

end

The first two line of the *when* clause work and I've tried to access objects farther down the tree in a similar fashion but it always throws an error "Unable to analyze expression".

I could solve the issue by extracting that data in a separate Java method and calling that method but if possible I'd prefer doing it Drools internally (it appears to me to be possible)

Thanks for any help

Leo K.

PS: If it helps this would be the Java method call to get the specified data:

```
normalisedMetaDataContainer.getMetaDataContainer()
.getNormalisedOrder().getSelection().getColumn()
.get(0).getAttributeCondition().getCondition()
.get(0).getAttrValueGroup().get(0).getValueGroup()
.getValueRange().get(0).getAttributeValueFrom()
```

Note I don't only want to get the first objects in the arrays but all of them as I want to check the rule on all objects present.

If you need additional information I'll be happy to provide.

Comment: Not seeing the Java classes G10EValidationObject, NormalisedDataColType, QualifiedAttributeNameValueGroupType at least with the types of the fields that are used here it's impossible to provide anything but guesswork.

Comment: This reply might be really late. But I managed to solve the issue. Or rather changed the premises so that this problem doesn't arise anymore.

Thank you regardless for your willingness to help. :)

Comment: You might delete the question. It's just a red herring now.